# How to detect if content assist is open in a SourceViewer

Tags: eclipse, jface

I am using a `SourceViewer` with a `ContentAssistant` configured like this:

```java
public class MySourceViewerConfiguration extends TextSourceViewerConfiguration {
  @Override
  public IContentAssistant getContentAssistant(ISourceViewer sourceViewer) {
    ContentAssistant assistant= new ContentAssistant();
    ...
    return assistant;
  }
}

SourceViewer sourceViewer = ...
sourceViewer.configure( new MySourceViewer() );
```

How can I determine if the content assist is currently active, i.e. if the proposal popup window is open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no way to query the `SourceViewer` directly whether the content assist is active.

However, if a completion listener is installed early enough before the `SourceViewer` is put into use, it can be used to track *assist sessions*.

For example:

```java
class ContentAssistListener implements ICompletionListener {

  boolean contentAssistActive;

  @Override
  public void assistSessionStarted( ContentAssistEvent event ) {
    contentAssistActive = true;
  }

  @Override
  public void assistSessionEnded( ContentAssistEvent event ) {
    contentAssistActive = false;
  }

  @Override
  public void selectionChanged( ICompletionProposal proposal, boolean smartToggle ) {
  }
}
```

The `contentAssistActive` field will be `true` if the content assist is currently active and `false` otherwise.